# Refactoring group of yeild return statments to a method

Tags: c#, yield, yield-return

How would I go about grouping multiple yield statements to a method ?

I have the following code :

```
public IEnumerable<IPublisher> RegisterEvents()
{
    var url= Settings.wcfUrl;
    var publisher = PublisherFactory.Create<IWcfPublisher> (url)
        publisher.Register(new object(..));
        publisher.Register(new object(..));
     yield return publisher;

    var url = Settings.webpublisherurl;
    var publisher = PublisherFactory.Create<IWebPublisher> (url)
        publisher.Register(new object(..));
        publisher.Register(new object(..));
     yield return publisher;

    var url = Settings.webpublisherurl2;
    var publisher = PublisherFactory.Create<IWebPublisher2> (url)
        publisher.Register(new object(..));
        publisher.Register(new object(..));
     yield return publisher;
     . . .
}
```

The code is getting very large and I wanted to refactor some of the publishers to a static class EventHelper

```
public IEnumerable<IPublisher> RegisterEvents()
{
    var url= Settings.wcfUrl;
    var publisher = PublisherFactory.Create<IWcfPublisher> (url)
        publisher.Register(new object(..));
        publisher.Register(new object(..));
     yield return publisher;

    return yield EventHelper.CreateWebApiPublisher() //<-- compiler error
     . . .
}
```

`CreateWebApiPublisher()` looks like

```
public static IEnumerable<IPublisher> CreateWebApiPublisher()
{
    var url = Settings.webpublisherurl;
    var publisher = PublisherFactory.Create<IWebPublisher>(url)
    publisher.Register(new object(..));
    publisher.Register(new object(..));
    yield return publisher;

    var url = Settings.webpublisherurl2;
    var publisher = PublisherFactory.Create<IWebPublisher2>(url)
    publisher.Register(new object(..));
    publisher.Register(new object(..));
    yield return publisher;
}
```

I am confused how to use `EventHelper.CreateWebApiPublisher()` in `RegisterEvents()` 
I keep getting  compiler error :

```
Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<IPublisher>' to 'IPublisher'...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yield return` can only yield a single value at a time.  At the line where you're getting the compiler error, you need to iterate through the results of the method instead, and `yield return` them sequentially.

```
foreach (var p in EventHelper.CreateWebApiPublisher())
    yield return p;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the return type of your function to be IPublisher instead of an enumerable, and don't yeild in it. Your function should only return one, and then you can yield the call. Pass in any requirements as parameters.